# Classification up to homeomorphism of closed Seifert fibered spaces.

Tags: geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Recently I read Matthew G. Brin's lecture notes on Seifert fibered spaces, in which the homeomorphism classifications of Seifert fibered spaces with boundaries are given. Loosely speaking, with some exceptions, the classifications up to homeomorphism and fiber-preserving homeomorphism of Seifert fibered spaces with boundaries identify. He mentioned that this lecture ended before he could give the homeomorphism classifications of closed Seifert fibered spaces. I want to know the results for closed cases but can't find proper material. Thanks for any advice or comment.

Comment: See for instance, the books J.Hempel "3-manifolds" or P.Orlik "Seifert manifolds."

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations!